# Woocommerce Composite Product Dynamically Change Featured Image Based on a Selection

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am building an online store (Computer Store to be precise).  I'm having a problem figuring out how to change a composite products image to another image dynamically based on a selection. (Case)  I've asked the question on woo-themes to no avail.  Is this even possible using only template files and not hard-coding into the plugin itself?

Comment: Any luck finding an answer?

Comment: No sir, didn't even find a plugin that did what I'm asking.  Seems to be a bit difficult to work around all of the files associated with the way woo-commerce handles things.

Comment: I have a similar issue, the closest I came to achieving complex product visuals was to use the Composite Product add-on with variable sub-products (and thumbnails enabled). If you choose the 'component' layout option you can set a generic image for each component (hard drive, for instance), which then gets swapped for the component the user selects. It's a neat solution.

Comment: The issue is that using variable products means you have to make a "version" for each module + other modules, with 2 items this is fine, but when you have a large library of items to choose from in each category, and you have multiple categories that turns into a big task quickly.

Comment: @DavidMoore Did you find a solution?